# How to extract the file modification time of a scraped image?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape part of a part-website that contain images of the parts, to collect some statistics. However, there is no url or image upload or creation date, so I have to use the approximate image file *modification-date* to get this info. Using *cURL*, this is an easy task with:

```
curl -sI https://path.to.com/blahblah_123/item_picture.jpg |grep "last-modified"
```

However, I think it would be more convenient to get this within the *scrapy* spider. But I have no idea if scrapy supports this at all, since I cannot find it in the documentation.

**Is there a way to get the *last-modified* date of a scraped image in scrapy?**

Comment: You can use `python-requests` instead of Scrapy and get required header value as `requests.get('https://path.to.com/blahblah_123/item_picture.jpg').headers['last-modified']`

Comment: This is also a very good alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [Scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#response-objects), the `response` has a `headers` dict field.

So you can access the `last-modified` with `response.headers.get('Last-Modified')`.

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea why I didn't think of looking there.